# The "elasticity of substitution" tag is misspelled

Tags: bug, tags

The tag for "elasticity of substitution" is currently spelled "elasticity-of-substit**ui**on". It would be great if a moderator could please rename that tag to insert the missing "t".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag was renamed. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.